the wifi on my viao computer seems to be dying ubuntu 24.04
Can anyone recommend a WiFi dongle that will work with 24.04.1 Ubuntu?

You are a bit off-topic for askubuntu, questions such as "which is the best..." are considered "opinion-based". I think you should post this question on ubuntu forums. That said, I would answer you if I knew the answer.
